# Create a text file in Javascript then send it with a ajax post to a Java server

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, post

I have a very large json to send (2 million characters and up). I cannot change the maximum of characters of a request received by the server.

I thought of writing it in a file and then sending it to the server, but I am unable to get the file.

Is my ajax post wrong? Is there a way to get the file?

My Javascript code:

```
var formData = new FormData();
var str = JSON.stringify(json);
var data = encode( str );
var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});
formData.append("localfile", blob, "filename.txt");
formData.append('a', 'excelExport');

AJS.$.ajax({
        url: AJS.params.baseURL + "/plugins/servlet/export",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        cache : false,
        async : false,
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            //Something
        },
        error: function (data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //Something
        }
    });
```

My Java code:

```
@MultipartConfig
public class ExportServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

request.getParts(); // Is empty
request.getParameters("a"); // null

StringBuffer jb = new StringBuffer();
    String line = null;
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            jb.append(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        /* report an error */ }

    String data = jb.toString(); // Contains my data with format ------WebKitFormBoundaryTq8jWlDRuF8aMBWRContent-Disposition: form-data; name="localfile"; filename="filename.txt"Content-Type: application/octet-stream"...

}
```

Comment: If it is JSON, why are you using `application/octet-stream`?  Why aren't you `JSON.stringify`ing and then sending as `text/plain` or even `application/json`?

Comment: Have you tried setting the contentType to 'multipart/form-data'?  I believe this is required to send files in a request.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data#The_enctype_attribute

Comment: Yes, I tried the contentType set to 'multipart/form-data'. I didn't try to make the blob with the 'text/plain', but I just did and it does the same thing.